# logging out automatically from other browser tabs

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to develop a functionality in JSP-Servlets where I need to log out an user when he logs out from other tab of the same browser.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if browser opens a new tab it shares the same session. So if session is invalidated it will automatically logout the user from the other tab.

I hope you have a security filter that checks if the user session is still valid. And redirects to login screen if user session is not valid.